# socket.io not receiving messages on server

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

server sided code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
io.once('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log(`New connection`)
  socket.emit('hello', 'hello from the server')
  socket.on('clientData', (data) => {
    console.log(data)
  })
})
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server started: http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Client side code:

```
var socket = io()
var hello = 'Hello server'
socket.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('established connection')
    socket.emit('clientData', hello)
})
socket.on('hello', function(data) {
  console.log(data)
})
```

When run the client doesnt emit the 'clientData' for some reason, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Replace `socket.on('connection' ...)` with `socket.on('connect' ...)` and it should work

Answer (score 1):

I think your `socket.on("connection",` use on the client is misguided. The connection event happens at the server when new clients join.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').Server(app)
const io = require('socket.io')(server)
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // #2 - This will run for the new connection 'socket' and set up its callbacks
  // #3 - send to the new client a 'hello' message
  socket.emit('hello', 'hello from the server') 
  socket.on('clientData', (data) => {
    // #6 - handle this clients 'clientData'
    console.log(data)
  })
})
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started: http://localhost:${port}")
})
```

Client side code:

```
// #1 - this will connect to the server and send the 'connection' 
var socket = io()
var hello = 'Hello server'
socket.on('hello', function(data) {
  // #4 - 'hello' response after connecting
  console.log(data)
  // #5 - send 'clientData' 
  socket.emit('clientData', hello)
})
```

Comment: Thanks!After an hour someone with a correct Answer!